# Using VBA to insert formula into cell with variable row numbers

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've got my spreadsheet set up so that when text is entered in column `Z`, `AutoFill` macro is called.

I need columns `AA` and `AB` to be autofilled with a formula up until the last row of text in column `Z`. I was using the `.AutoFill`:

```
'Range("AA3:AB3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA3:AB" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillValues
```

`AA3` Starting formula was: `=IF(AC3="",IF(Y3="","",AB2),AC3)`

`AB3` Starting formula was: `=IF(AD3="",IF(AA3="","",WORKDAY(AA3,(Y3/8))),AD3)`

This worked ok but there are times where the cells value are manually entered which takes away the original formula, then messing up the autofill for the rest of the cells. So I took away the auto fill and added a set formula with variable row numbers using `ActiveCell.Row`.

This is what I have now:

```
Sub AutoFill()

Application.EnableEvents = False

lastRow = Range("Z900").End(xlUp).Row


Range("AA" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Formula = "=IF(AC" & ActiveCell.Row & "="", IF(Y" & ActiveCell.Row & "="","",AB" & ActiveCell.Row - 1 & "),AC" & ActiveCell.Row & ")"
Range("AB" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Formula = "=IF(AD" & ActiveCell.Row & "="",IF(AA" & ActiveCell.Row & "="","",WORKDAY(AA" & ActiveCell.Row & ", (Y" & ActiveCell.Row & "/8))),AD" & ActiveCell.Row & ")"

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Now I get a runtime error and the first `"Range("AA"..."` is highlighted. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: You may need to double-up on the internal double quotes.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! For some reason when I enter the data in column Z, it ads the formula to the next row down rather than adjacent. It didn't do that with the .Autofill function.

Comment: Trying to insert formulas via *VBA* that contain double quotes can be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it to

```
Range("AA3:AA" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(AC3="""",IF(Y3="""","""",AB2),AC3)"
Range("AB3:AB" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(AD3="""",IF(AA3="""","""",WORKDAY(AA3,(Y3/8))),AD3)"
```

The row numbers that don't have `$` will be auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

All quotations with blanks `""` were changed to `""""`. Quotations within quotations. This fixed the runtime error to allow the formula to work.

```
Range("AA" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Formula = "=IF(AC" & ActiveCell.Row & "="""", IF(Y" & ActiveCell.Row & "="""","""",AB" & ActiveCell.Row - 1 & "),AC" & ActiveCell.Row & ")"
Range("AB" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Formula = "=IF(AD" & ActiveCell.Row & "="""",IF(AA" & ActiveCell.Row & "="""","""",WORKDAY(AA" & ActiveCell.Row & ", (Y" & ActiveCell.Row & "/8))),AD" & ActiveCell.Row & ")"
```